# How can I determine the scale range in y axis in Seaborn Line Graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to arrange the values of y-axis in seaborn graph.
I want to increase number in such kind of order -> 100,1000,10000

How can I do that.

I can use this seaborn graph code defined below.

```
ax = sns.lineplot
```

Comment: Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get better response for your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ax.set_yticks` and pass a list of ticker values you want to set on y axis (and `ax.set_xticks` for x axis)

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x, y);
ax.set_yticks([100,1000,10000])
```

And of course you can generate your list using list comprehension

```
yticks = [10**i for i in range(2, 5)]
ax.set_yticks(yticks)
```

Alternately, you can also use `ax.set_ylim` which takes a start and end value. 
`ax.set_ylim(100, 1000)`, but I don't think you can specify the increment in this function.